# Use Foreach Loop in SSIS to see if a condition is met then move to next container

Tags: sql, ssis

Trying to use a query like this:

```
Select * from MyTable
where CompletedDate >= [@PackageStartTime]
```

Query I have in my SQL Task:

```
Select * from MyTable
where CompletedDate >= ?
```

Need to loop through the query to see if the condition is met and if it is, move to the next task and if not, keep looping until the condition is met.

Tried using this Query in SQL Task with a variable name of [@StartTime] and Result Set of Result Name = 0 and Variable Name = User:Query to put the results in.  The User:Query is set to Object.

In the Foreach Loop container below that is the Collection "Foreach ADO Enumerator" and ADO object source variable:  User:Query and Enumeration mode:  Rows in the first table.

I think I got the first part working but what do I put in the Foreach Loop container at this point?  I need a variable to say that condition is TRUE to move on to the next task.

Comment: A screenshot or two might help. The "condition" you are referring to is "does the query return results, yeah" If so, carry on. Otherwise, wait and then re-run said query?

Comment: It seems like you may have honed in on using a foreach loop when you could rely more on the control flow (even if you need to use containers to isolate). You are not really articulating your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a sql task to give me a constraint to work with. Something like below...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE CompletedDate >= @PackageStartTime
```

Then save the result set to a var and setup a constraint to your next task. Something like this

```
@[User::RowCount] > 0
```

Comment: I'm not completely sure what your doing but you also say you want to "keep looping until the condition is met." It looks like you found out how to do that with the Foreach loop. You could cursor your way through it as well although it can be problematic and I wouldn't do it but it will work.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments.  I ended up using a ForLoop instead of a ForEach Loop and used the Counter variable in there.  Since I wasn't looping through but one thing, I found some articles on Stack that were using something simliar, although I made mine work with the different loop.